# Centering brand in bootstrap nav bar

Tags: navigation, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, nav

Can anyone point me to a resource on how to center the brand logo within the nav bar? I'd love to be able to lay out my nav bar like this:

Large screen:

[link1] [link2] [link3] [BRAND LOGO] [link4] [link5] [link6]

Med screen:

[stack links1-3] [BRAND LOGO] [stack links4-6]

Small screen

[BRAND LOGO] [default pulldown nav menu]

Any ideas?

Comment: Here's a start: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/pvxGN/).  Not exactly what you're asking for, but I don't have time right now to take it any further.  You're definitely going to need to use media queries to get all those various states available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [twitter bootstrap -- center brand in nav bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504382/twitter-bootstrap-center-brand-in-nav-bar)