# Twitter Bootstrap V 3.0 dynamically centering navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap v3.0

Id like to dynamically center the navigation bar. i.e. A fix that doesnt hardcode a width.

How is this achieved? Below is a sample of the standard navigation code with excess tags removed.

```
<!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">All Saints Church, Ripley.</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" >
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- ./NAVBAR -->
```

The documentation states to float the navbar right insert .navbar-right @`<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">` ... shown here http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment.

Having followed the methodology of this question: [twitter bootstrap -- center brand in nav bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504382/twitter-bootstrap-center-brand-in-nav-bar) I cannot centralize the navigation using margin-left: auto; and margin-right: auto;

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to center all of the navbar links, the entire navbar, or just the `brand`?

Comment: I would like to know how to center the entire navbar but in this instance I only want to center the navbar links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, I don't quite like this solution =) But a brute force way may be to add the following CSS:

```
.nav.navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

and the following jQuery to force the width down from the `auto` that is being inherited from `.container`:

```
var width = 0, $navbarLinks = $(".nav.navbar-nav");

$navbarLinks.children().each( function(idx) {
    width += $(this).outerWidth();
});

$navbarLinks.width(width);
```

See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lebolo/mj28w/) for testing.

Comment: This works very nicely @lebolo - thank you :D 

The only issue, on mobile devices it causes the carat to be placed under the dropdown menu and causes the 'active' highlighting to not fully span the active element.

Answer (score 0):

I have found it easiest to use the `nav-justified` class for this purpose..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>    
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav nav-justified">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

## [Demo](http://bootply.com/98325)

You can also constrain the width using an extra class. See the 2nd navbar in the demo.

Comment: Brilliant. Its exactly what i asked for so thank you very much for that @Skelly.

The trade off against not having navbar-nav in the code makes the solution untenable for myself.

I've sifted through the CSS and found: 

`.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}`

`.navbar-nav.pull-right > li > .dropdown-menu,
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu.pull-right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
`.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav.navbar-left:first-child {
    margin-left: -15px;
  }`

appear to be the only positioning css styles.

Comment: all of the above css styles i got from bootstrap.css.

I'm trying to understand why i cant retain the color, padding, margin settings and remove any styles that might affect positioning. so far everything ive tried just winds up in a mess.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the BS classes are geared towards left/right nav links, but not centered links. I don't know why.

Comment: Must be a an issue they've chosen to leave for now. I dont believe its an oversight and they didn't anticipate people wanting centered navbar links.