# Unable to center website brand in navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to center my website's brand in the navbar using bootstrap 3.0 and have been unsuccessful in doing so. I have tried both of these solutions:
[twitter bootstrap -- center brand in nav bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504382/twitter-bootstrap-center-brand-in-nav-bar)
[Bootstrap: center some navbar items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824914/bootstrap-center-some-navbar-items)
And neither has worked for me. Here is my current code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">My Website's Brand</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I have tried text-align: center and auto margins and nothing has worked. Any ideas?
EDIT: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Kqn8/

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap can be a difficult thing to manipulate at times.  Usually with a library like that, you mostly have to take what you can get. +1 because I couldn't find a reasonable solution quickly.

Comment: seems like @bozdoz answer works on the JSFiddle...

Comment: @AttilaTheFun bozdoz's answer works when you add width:100%; to the .navbar-header

Comment: @Yani You're right.  That's another solution, but I decided to set float to none instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a couple of overwrites for the bootstrap classes, namely the following:

```
.navbar-header {
    padding-top:15px;
    text-align:center;
    float:none;
}
.navbar-brand {
    float:none;
}
```

`.navbar-brand` is floated left, most importantly.  So you need to set float to none.  `navbar-header` needs `text-align:center` to center, and `padding-top:15px` to adjust for the padding styling that is removed when you remove the float.  Probably some better ways to do this, but this is the most basic solution.

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/KDsJ8/

### Update

You also need to set .navbar-header to `float:none` since on different screen sizes it will float left. :P

Fiddle updated.

Comment: :(
In the jsfiddle it is still left justified.

Comment: @AttilaTheFun Ha!  You're right! At least, sometimes you're right. Bootstrap has a bunch of media queries to change styling for different browser sizes.  Let me adjust.

Comment: @AttilaTheFun Fixed.  Sorry about that.  Didn't notice.

Comment: bozdoz, thank you so much! It works now! I marked yours as correct and upvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

```
.navbar-header {
    text-align: center;
 }
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/ujgdL/

---

EDIT: Bootstrap update.

```
.navbar-header { text-align: center;  }
.navbar-brand { display: inline-block; float: none; }
```

working example http://jsfiddle.net/3Kqn8/1/

Comment: That doesn't use Bootstrap and doesn't work with it.

Comment: Missing  width:100%; at the header

Comment: @AlienArrays Works now, but your solution suffers from the same thing mine did: you need to set navbar-header to float none as well, for all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I also have another solution below:

```
.navbar-header {
    text-align:center; // Align center will work after we clear the "Float" in ".navbar-brand"
    line-height: 50px; // To make our text to vertical align to middle;
}
.navbar-brand {
    float: none; // Clear the float for align the text
    display: block; // To Make it click on the hold box
}
```